# How to sort a list which has two set of elements into two alphabetically ordered sets list

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have a list with two kinds of elements - Free items and Paid items.

I want to sort the list such that the paid items will be in the first part of the list and the free items in the second part of the list.

I have a set of comparators like A-Z sort, Z-A sort, Type sort.

Whatever be the sort type, it should always display the final list as paid items in the first part of the list and the free items in the second part of the list and each set in the list sorted based on the comparator(A-z or Z-A..etc).

Foe eg.

I have three Paid items and five free items.
When I sort the full list on A-Z, it should display three Paid items in A-Z sort and then Free items in A-Z sort order.

I would like to know how to implement this.

---

Update with code snippets:

The list contains items with names {APaid, MFree, OFree, BPaid, NFree, PFree, CPaid, QFree}

```
Collections.sort(myList, new UtilityClass.TitleComparatorAtoZ());  

public static class TitleComparatorAtoZ implements Comparator
    {

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            int result = 0;

            if ((o1 != null) && (o2 != null))
            {
                if (o1 instanceof Item && o2 instanceof Item)
                {
                    Item lmi1 = (Item) o1;
                    Item lmi2 = (Item) o2;

                    if ((lmi1.getName() != null) && (lmi2.getName() != null))
                    {
                        result = lmi1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(lmi2.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The final list should be  {APaid, BPaid, CPaid, MFree, NFree, OFree, PFree, QFree}..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is this:

Modify each of your comparator like this:

First compare the two object parameters based on whether it is paid or free item, then compare them based on A-Z etc...

//algorithm

Comparator(Object T1, Object T2)
Start

If T1 is paid and T2 is free return 1
else if T1 is free and T2 is paid return -1
else //both are free or paid, then compare based on A-Z starting character
    return (compare on starting character).

So, if you have a paid item which starts with Z, then it would be after the paid item starting with A.

Modified:

Collections.sort(myList, new UtilityClass.TitleComparatorAtoZ());

public static class TitleComparatorAtoZ implements Comparator
    {

```
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        int result = 0;

        if ((o1 != null) && (o2 != null))
        {
            if (o1 instanceof Item && o2 instanceof Item)
            {
                Item lmi1 = (Item) o1;
                Item lmi2 = (Item) o2;

                if ((lmi1.getName() != null) && (lmi2.getName() != null))
                {
                    if(lmi1.getName().endsWith("Paid") 
                       && lmi2.getName().endsWith("Free")) 
                    {
                         result = 1;
                    }
                    else if (lmi1.getName().endsWith("Free") 
                       && lmi2.getName().endsWith("Paid"))
                    {
                         result = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         result = lmi1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(lmi2.getName());

                    }

                                        }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate with my code snippet, how i should modify the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [using a second parameter als Comperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

It allows you to pass an instance of Comparator to sort according to your needs. For example, you can create a comperator to check on the variable `Name` of all the objects, or create a comperator to check on the variable `Type`.

With that comperator, you can sort the list out.

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
                            Comparator<? super T> c)
```

[There is a nice and easy example of this here.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

For example, you have the class `Fruit`. You can put the following code in this class:

```
public static Comparator<Fruit> FruitNameComparator 
                      = new Comparator<Fruit>() {

    public int compare(Fruit fruit1, Fruit fruit2) {

      String fruitName1 = fruit1.getFruitName().toUpperCase();
      String fruitName2 = fruit2.getFruitName().toUpperCase();

      //ascending order
      return fruitName1.compareTo(fruitName2);

      //descending order
      //return fruitName2.compareTo(fruitName1);
    }

};
```

And using that code, you can compare the names of the fruit anywhere using 
`Arrays.sort(fruits, Fruit.FruitNameComparator);`

Answer (score 0):

1. classify your list as to which is free items and which is paid items into 2 separate lists

   ```
   for ( X x : list ) {
       if ( isFreeItem ) {
           add to freeItemList
       } else {
           add to paidItemList
       }
   }
   ```
2. use your comparator class to sort each list separately

   ```
   Collections.sort(freeItemsList);
   Collections.sort(paidItemsList);
   ```
3. instantiate a new list and put your paidItemsList and freeItemsList accordingly

   ```
   List result = new ArrayList();
   for ( X x : paidItemsList ) {
       add to result
   }

   for ( X x : freeItemsList ) {
       add to result
   }
   ```

Comment: Thats a good idea, but i dont want to create an overhead by creating two lists and then sorting and then merging them. I am looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/15760975/449378 said by Shreyas.